In which episode did Lisa Simpson mention "the vapors"?
I'm trying to identify the Simpsons episode with a scene in which Lisa Simpson speaks as if she's a Southern belle. 
I don't think it's the episode "The Color Yellow" in which Lisa learns about her slave-owning ancestor and flashes back to that time -- I think it was a quick joke in a different episode -- but I'm not 100% sure about that.
The part I remember most clearly is that she speaks over-dramatically and uses the anachronistic phrases "the vapors" and "a body"... specifically she says something like "Oh, this commotion is enough to give a body a case of the vapors" (not an accurate quote, but catches the gist).
Other things I think I remember but not 100% sure:

The scene was set on a plantation in the antebellum South (pre-1860)
Lisa was wearing an old-fashioned dress
Was one of the Treehouse of Horror episodes, or some other non-standard story line
It's a brief moment, not a running gag through the entire episode

I've spent some time searching for combinations of terms like Lisa Simpson, Southern Belle, plantation and "the vapors" but haven't figured it out.

FWIW, i feel like i remember this as well, but spoken by Bart actually. I cannot find a clip or reference though.

Darn. I could have sworn this was from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_the_Alligator_and_Run, but it's not in the script.

Wasn't this the Huckleberry Finn Treehouse of Horrors? "Why, Huckleberry Finn! You get down from there! A body could break his neck!"
Nelson was Huckleberry. :) 
Hope this helps.
